# Continuous Sum Function

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I am trying to make a simple sum function that sums until I hit a blank cell. I am not sure why it is not working. I am trying to sum currency and have the output be a currency as well. So far I have:

```
Function SumContin(X)

Dim Ro As Long
Dim Col As Long
Dim Ro1 As Long
Dim Col1 As Long

Ro = Application.WorksheetFunction.Row(X)
Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Column(X)


Do While Cells(Ro, Col) <> ""
Sum = Sum + CInt(Cells(Ro, Col))
Ro = Ro - 1
Loop    

End Function
```

Comment: it was just pointed out to me that you're using CInt.  Why are you doing this, when you're summing currency?  Seems very bad, you should sum, and then round at the end.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

**UPD:**

Follow up from comments:

> Can I make the function where it will be =SumContin() and it starts from the cell above?

```
Function SumContin()
    Application.Volatile

    SumContin = 0

    On Error Resume Next
    With Application.ThisCell
        If .Row = 1 Then Exit Function
        If .Offset(-1) = "" Then Exit Function
        SumContin = Application.Sum(Range(.Offset(-1), .End(xlUp)))
    End With

End Function
```

**Note:** since code using `Application.ThisCell`, function will work only in case when you call it from worksheet: `=SumContin()` and won't work if you call it from any code

Comment: While all your answers seem correct and users seem happy to get their answers it would be nice to see some explanation along with the code. Keep that in mind as this is soft of the general rule that we like to follow on Stack Overflow. +1 :>

Comment: I realized I made a small mistake. I want to use this to continuously sum from the row above the function till I hit a blank. How would I reference the cell I am in? I was trying to start from the cell below and start two cells above like this:

`Function SumContin(X As Range)`
``
    `Dim Ro As Long`
    `Dim Col As Long`

    `Ro = X.Row`
    `Col = X.Column`
    
    `Ro = Ro - 2`
    
    `Sum = 0`

    `Do While Cells(Ro, Col) <> ""`
        `Sum = Sum + CInt(Cells(Ro, Col))`
        `Ro = Ro - 1`
    `Loop`

    `SumContin = Sum`
    
`End Function`

Comment: I just tried the updated answer. It is not working. What should my X value be? Can I make the function where it will be =SumContin() and it starts from the cell above?

Comment: When trying to compile I am getting an error Method 'Thiscell' of object'_Application' Failed. From this: With Application.ThisCell. I am not sure what the error could be.

Comment: 1) what excel version do you using? 2) have you call this function from another macro or from worksheet?

Comment: You can't use a formula in a cell in the range, since that would be a circular reference.  If your range you want to add is A2:A8, the formula must be in some other cell, like B1 for example.

Comment: I am using 2013 and I am using this macro on this worksheet. What could be the issue?

Comment: @user2800228, I understand! You can't compile this code using VBA, because in this case `Application.ThisCell` is unknown. Just try to call this function from worksheet in any cell: `=SumContin()`

Comment: @user2800228, try my updated code, just call this function from any cell like plain formula: `=SumContin()`

Comment: I am just trying to write something that keeps sums everything above it. So when I add rows it will automatically account for it.

Comment: Basically it's because you rounds each value `Sum = Sum + CInt(Cells(Ro, Col))` (`CInt()` do it). I've fixed it. Try now

Answer (score 0):

A UDF for this seems overkill given that in the A provided the requisite range has to be keyed in anyway. A running total something like `=SUM(A$1:A1)` and double-clicking on the fill handle may be more convenient at times.

Answer (score 0):

It would be most efficient to just define the range withing the UDF based on the cell passed, and then use the WorksheetFunction.Sum command.

Here's one way:

```
Function SumContin(X As Range)

SumContin = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(X.Address & ":" & X.End(xlDown).Address))

End Function
```

Comment: LanceRoberts, you would be right for plain sum, but notice that OP uses `Sum = Sum + CInt(Cells(Ro, Col))` and `CInt(Cells(Ro, Col))` takes only integer part of the value